# Finding biggest element index in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

Sample test cases:

**Input**

3              ------> length of dictionary

abcd 5 3 6 2  //dict elements  (key=list[0], value=list[1:])

ok 1 8 5 3    //

best 9 1 3 5  //

Expected output

abcd 2         ----> key and index of max ele of list

ok 1

best 0

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for the just the highest key ?

```
d = {15:3, 4:1, 11:2, 14:9}
print(max(d)) #gives max key
print(d[max(d)]) # gives max value
```